# Restoring bash prompt $PS1 to default

Tags: bash, shell-script, prompt

Is there a bash shell script or command that I can invoke to restore the original value to $PS1? I clobbered it without making a backup copy. If need be, I can always re-install bash, I'm hoping there is a less drastic method.

BTW, I'm using bash v5.2.26

Comment: How did you change it? Editing `.bashrc` or by directly setting `PS1=...`?

Comment: the builtin default is  `\s-\v\$ `, which gives something like `bash-5.2.26$ `. Other than that, it's set in the shell's startup files, of which there are many, both in `/etc` and in the user's home directory. So the question really is, what exactly did you do to clobber it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly how you destroyed your setting for `PS1`, you might find additional settings in the contents of `/etc/profile` or `/etc/skel/.profile` for instance.  "I clobbered it" doesn't exactly lend much specificity with respect to what you actually did.  If all you did was something akin to `unset PS1`, then `source`ing your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file would probably restore your prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In an effort to keep it simple, I left out key details.

My problem was entangled with the use of bash_completion; it turns out it is invoked twice upon my termux system startup, before the first prompt is displayed.

Once I unwound and disabled bash_completion, and restarted the system, the original prompt was restored.

BTW, somewhere in termux startup, $PS1 is set to `\[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \[\e[0;97m\]\$\[\e[0m\]`, which I don't understand.

Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to have helped.  The stuff you may not understand in that prompt are ANSI color codes that tell the terminal to color various prompt components.  `\e` is an Escape character which is part of that control sequence. `<ESC>[0;32m` is the ANSI sequence for "reset the color and then set the text to green" for example.